# How to get a short string after compressing/decompressing a string?

Tags: c#, .net, compression

How to get a short string when we compress a long string in C#.

I want to compress a long string into a short string (with minimum length) and also want to decompress it to get back my original string. With minimum length means if the original string length is 10, the compressed  string length must be half of original or less.

I don't want to use any Libraries other than .Net built in libraries.

```
For example: Original String: "Hello World" 
Compressed String: "$n(@3" //something like this.
```

I use different methods but they don't compress in this manner.Any help? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what language do you want the answer in? You posted 3 languages and one platform. Also, your problem definition is way too vague for a useful answer to be given (for example - "with minimum length" - _what_ minimum length)?

Comment: Any language like C++,C#.Net and VB.Net.I can convert it into my C#..With minimum length means if the original string length is 10, the compressed  string length must b half of original or less.

Comment: Most likely you're going to get unprintable characters or even non-unicode symbols in such a compressed string. What exactly are you trying to solve here, why do you need them compressed into new *strings*?

Comment: Do you really want to compress strings to strings? People usually compress byte arrays to byte arrays and that's different.

Comment: @Karlsen: I just want to save memory by compressing a string.

Comment: If you just want to compress it, who cares what it looks like if you print out the compressed value. The concern should be that it does compress.

Comment: No, I want to compress in a way that it saves my memory not just encode my string.

Comment: Guys, I must downvote the question. Nobody actually understands it and nobody knows why one should really compress strings like this. Bad question.

Comment: @AI kepp: If you don't understand my question then ask me. So, I can clear your point.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the "compressed string"?

Comment: @Karles: I save the compresses string with minimum length in my database so it reduces the database size.

Comment: @mirfan: Do you want a hash? Or do you want to re-create the original string from the compressed string?

Comment: @mirfan: have you verified that you *really* need to do this, or are you just trying to think ahead and try to save space? How many strings, and how long are they on average? ie. how "bad" is this problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Karles: It may contain 100 or 200 characters.

Comment: @Karles: If you have multiple long strings and you want to save these strings in database with minimum storage. What should you do?

Comment: How many strings? Are you *trying* to be vague? To answer your question; I wouldn't, unless I *knew* it was my responsibility to handle this problem. Disk space is cheap, and unless you got a *really* big problem, it isn't going to be worth it. Remember that you have to bugfix all edge-cases. Have you thought about strings having a collation in the database? The only way to be sure that what you save is what you retrieve, you have to encode it with printable characters, which increase the size again.

Comment: It may be Number of thousand strings or more.

Comment: @mirfan00 There is no reason to do this, and every reason not to do this. You will not save significant space, and you render your database unsearchable. Storage space is the cheapest commodity available to you. The savings for "thousands of strings" of "100 to 200 characters" is going to be insignificant, less than a megabyte. **Don't do this**, store your strings uncompressed.

Comment: Voted to close: Sometimes we have to help people to avoid shooting themselves in the foot by taking away their ability to aim the shotgun. This is one of those times.

Comment: **OK guys. It's all my fault....**

Answer (score 5):

Arbitrary guaranteed compression is impossible (See for example http://matt.might.net/articles/why-infinite-or-guaranteed-file-compression-is-impossible/).

Comment: I think it is possible. The question said nothing about *lossless* compression. ;-)

Comment: I think the problem is that question didn't say much at all about it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) which is .NET since 2.0.

```
private static string CompressLongString(string longString)
{
    MemoryStream outstream = new MemoryStream();
    MemoryStream instream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(longString));

    using (GZipStream compress = 
        new GZipStream(outstream, 
        CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        instream.CopyTo(compress);

    }

    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outstream.GetBuffer());
}
```

Comment: With the preamble, the result will probably be _longer_ for short strings.

Comment: @Oded Of course. But is the the question not saying **"compress a long string"**?

Comment: GZipStream is not for strings of characters, it is for byte streams.

Comment: String can be represented in a stream. You use `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myString)`or any other encoding which is appropriate and initialize a memory stream with it.

Comment: @Alostad: It will give you a long compressed string. I used it.

Comment: @Aliostad: He expressively wanted to compress string to string. Not string to stream. Who knows what he really needs, but this was asked.

Comment: @Mirfan00 What is short what is long???? Define it first and then ask the question.

Comment: Strings can be converted to byte streams easily enough...

Comment: The `MemoryStreams` should be in the using statement as well. Also, to get only printable characters on the output, use `Convert.ToBase64String` - compression ratio will decrease, though.

Comment: @mirfan, I understand that english is not your primary language, but please try to make sense. A string that "contains maximum values" makes no sense. Do you mean "maximum length string"? ie. 2GB? or do you just mean "a very long string"?

Comment: I don't think that you want to help me.

Comment: -1: The code as shown is not guaranteed to create proper Unicode symbols. It isn't safe. Also, throwing that string to a database into a string-based field is almost guaranteed to go wrong. The bytes needs to be encoded into printable characters, using Base64 or Base85 or similar.

Comment: @mirfan: The problem is that you're on the wrong path. Can you post some *real* examples? Like an actual string you want to compress? Since you seem to be trying very hard to be as vague as possible, it isn't possible to actually help you.

Comment: @Karles: May be I am wrong. But I want to save disk space.

Comment: If you have this little disk-space, you're in much bigger problems than trying to save less than 1MB of disk-space in your database, adding more code and bugs to your applications, and rendering your database unsearchable and unreadable. Note that "1MB of savings" is if you magically managed to compress 5000 strings averaging 200 characters down to nothing. This is not possible, at most you're going to save a few hundred kilobytes. Listen to what people are telling you: **it is not worth it!**

Comment: **OK guys. It's all my fault....**

Answer (score 1):

What is your real prolem? If you want to save memory by compressing a very long string, then you can convert it to `byte[]` array in UTF-8. Create a `MemoryStream` object, then create `StreamWriter` in UTF-8 on that `MemoryStream` and write your string to there. Then close streamwriter and stream and use `ToArray()` to convert it to a compact array. Although this will create many temporary objects, the resulting array will be often much smaller than original string.

Note that this is not compression, just encoding characters to UTF-8, which is usually 50% smaller than UTF-16 normally used in strings. And it is done using standard .NET library as you requested. (But result is not literally a string as you wanted.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GZipStream:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/GZipStream.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I understand you want to save database size.

Compressing strings with 10 characters, does not gain you very much. And is not garanteed to win a certain percentage (you cannot compress an already compressed string).

You could store every string in a table (with the string and a numeric primary key), and reference the string with just the key from your other tables. If you have repeating strings. If your string do not repeat, you might break each string into words, and store the indexes of the words.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest magic. A string is just a series of numbers, none of which can be discarded and keep the string the same. Therefore, to compress the string you would need to decide if there is any of the string you can live without and makes rules to do that. i can't think of any common ways, so you would have to make your own rules.